# invalid parameter while retrieving blob with c#

Tags: c#, mysql

i'm trying to retrieve a picture saved in the database in BLOB format
but it gives an Exception that the parameter of MemoryStream is invalid in this Line

```
pictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
```

and this is the full code :

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.IO;

namespace InsertImage2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;port=****;username=****;password=****;");
        MySqlCommand cmd;
        MySqlDataAdapter da;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string query = "select * from images_database.images where id = '"+textBox1.Text+"';";
            cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, myConn);
            da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);

            byte[] img = (byte[])dt.Rows[0][1];
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(img);
            pictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
            da.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Think (**do not try!**) what would happen if you entered the following text into `textBox1`: `';drop table images_database;--`

Comment: Required reading: [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight : what has that got to do with the problem?

Comment: @PaulF Look at the `string query = "select * ...` line.

Comment: Why would that give an exception when reading the data?

Comment: @jad: have you checked the query does return an image & that it is in the second column - your code resembles mine which works to retrieve JPEGS.

Comment: @PaulF dt.rows[0][0] returns the index and dt.rows[0][1] returns a System.Byte[]

Comment: @jadsalah: Have you got MySQL workbench installed - if so can you check the data in the table is valid.